Can I add a GFCI receptacle to the light circuit in my bathroom?
I have a 4" sq. metal box with 2 cables feeding the location. 1 cable is standard romex with a hot and neutral- no ground. The other cable is old cloth insulated with a hot, neutral and a ground, which is grounded to the metal box.  I have pulled and separated the wires and put a volt meter to them all and I don't know what to make of the findings!

Cable 1 (romex)

hot wire = 43.6 volts
Neutral = 61.7 volts


Cable 2 (old wire)

hot = 8.5 volts
Neutral = 61.7 volts



When I put the leads from the multi meter on the hot and neutral I get a total volts from the romex of 115.3 volts and the old cable is 51.1 volts.
Now, there may have been a fan in t h e bathroom in the past but it has been removed and the only other factor is that this circuit is shared with the exterior security lighting.

The title gives a very specific question (which I can answer, but not yet because...) The content raises very serious issues about voltages. You may have bad connections. You may have bad or floating ground. You may have phantom voltage. What values do you get if the breaker is off? Was there a switch between cables 1 and 2 that was removed? Pictures would help too.


The voltage readings are likely meaningless induced voltage, if measured with a high-impedance meter, not under load. Particularly since on the Romex, you don't state what two wires you're testing. 2. Yes, it certainly is possible to change over to GFCI outlets, and is required in bathrooms by most codes.


That security lighting makes it a no-go
Your idea won't work because having the security lighting on a combination bathroom lighting and receptacle circuit violates NEC 210.11(C)(3):

(3) Bathroom Branch Circuits
In addition to the number of branch circuits required by other parts of this section, one or more 120-volt, 20-ampere branch circuit shall be provided to supply bathroom(s) receptacle outlet(s) required by 210.52(D) and any countertop and similar work surface receptacle outlets. Such circuits shall have no other outlets.
Exception: Where the 20-ampere circuit supplies a single bathroom, outlets for other equipment within the same bathroom shall be permitted to be supplied in accordance with 210.23(B)(1) and (B)(2).

